# $L^1$ convergence equivalency

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

For integrable $X_n,X$, I am trying to show that $X_n\xrightarrow{L^1} X$ if and only if $E(X_nI_A)\to E(X I_A)$ uniformly for all sets $A$. Why is this not trivial?

the one way, if $E|X_n-X|\to 0$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. Thus by the equivalency of weak convergence we have that $E(f(X_n)X)\to E(f(X))$ for all continuous $f$. Choosing $f(x)=xI_A$ we are done. The converse direction, why cant we take $A=\Omega$ and be done?

Additionally, under what minimal conditions can we impose to have that $X_n \to X$ in probability implies convergence in $L^1$?

Comment: You didn't prove the convergence $\mathbb{E}[X_nI_A]\to\mathbb{E}[XI_A]$ is uniform in $A$. And in the other direction, the condition $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\to\mathbb{E}[X]$ doesn't imply convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: Your function $f(x)=x I_A$ is not a function of only $x$, it is a function of $x$ and $\omega$ (the outcome). Convergence in distribution is too weak for what you are trying to show.

Comment: For that direction you can use triangle inequality and/or Jensen’s inequality. For other direction, you want to define sets $A$ that depend on $X$ and $X_n$.

Comment: @Michael, the triangle inequality will get me $E|X_n|->E|X|$ at best, which wont help me with uniform convergence on all sets. furthermore for the other direction, I have tried using sets of form $A:={|X_n|>n}$ but this wont help either.

Comment: I observe that $$X_nI_A \leq XI_A + |X_n-X| \quad \forall A, n$$ For the other direction of the "if and only if" statement you want to use sets of the type $X_n-X\geq \epsilon$. {Generally speaking, you want to treat $(X_n,X)$ together and not treat $X_n$ and $X$ in isolation.   Note that if $W, Z$ are i.i.d. uniform over $[0,1]$ then $E[W]=E[Z]$ but $E[|W-Z|]\neq 0$, which shows why treating $W, Z$ in isolation tells little about $|W-Z|$.}

Comment: Okay I got the first part,

Comment: For the second part we have that, if $A_n={|X_n-X|<\varepsilon}$ then 

$$ E|X_n-X| \le   E|(X_n-X)I_{A_n}|+E|(X_n-X)I_{A_n^c}|$$  

One of those at worst is $\varepsilon$ and the other doesn't vanish necessarily so this is an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me expand on the hint given to you by @Michael:

As he suggested, let $n$ be arbitrary, and take your sets $A_n := X_n - X > \epsilon$. You then have that

$E[(X_n - X)1_{A_n}] < \delta$ where this $\delta$ is independent of $\epsilon$. (since the convergence is uniform over the sets, you can pick whichever set you want for sufficiently large $n$. We will pick a set that depends on that $n$)

Now, do the same with $B_n := X - X_n > \epsilon$ to get $E[(X_n - X)1_{B_n}] < \delta$

Now, note that $|X - X_n| \leq (X - X_n) A_n + \epsilon + (X - X_n) B_n + \epsilon$, so now taking expectations of both sides, we get that $E[|X - X_n|] \leq 2 \epsilon + 2 \delta$. Since $\epsilon$ was chosen independently of $\delta$, you can make their sum arbitrarily small.